# Regex - parse date with optional characters

Tags: regex

I try to parse a date from a string with format `dd/MM/yyyy`. My regex is `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`.

The question is, how to extract the date string when I have some extra characters like `dd/ MM  /yyyy` or any other characters whose are not a digit or `/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\d\/]*` would match zero-to-N non-digit-or-slash characters.  But I'm not sure that's really what you'd want - it might consume a lot more than you expect if you're passing it a big chunk of text.  It might be better to limit the kinds of extra characters you're willing to let pass through (E.g. only whitespace?) so you fail more reliably on invalid input.

(and, then, to extract the date, you'd just want to put capture parens around each of the three numeric portions, and concatenate them together after the match)

So a complete answer might be

`(\d{2})[^\d\/]*\/[^\d\/]*(\d{2})[^\d\/]*\/[^\d\/]*(\d{4})`

(though the escaping requirements and capture methods may vary depending on your language/reg-ex library - this works in perl.  And you could also make it a little more flexible and allow one-digit days and months if you want.)