# Can't find a way to select only a part of a string

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to select, with regex, the hour on multiple date like this : 2016-02-13 19:48:57. In this case I would like to get 19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - parse date with optional characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131862/regex-parse-date-with-optional-characters)

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even use regex here, use `strptime` instead:

```
dt = '2016-02-13 19:48:57'
obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(obj.hour)
```

If you didn't want to use `strptime` for some reason, then the next best thing might be to just take a substring of your datetime string:

```
print(dt[11:13])
19
```

Comment: Thank you ! The first one was what I was looking for. The second one I can't use it because I have a dataset and maybe some data are not written with the same amount of number.